# Cordova SQL code does not work

Tags: javascript, sql, cordova

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<!--
This is an example that shows how to create an application that uses
an embedded sqlite database
in a mobile device (iphone,ipod,ipad,android using phonegap, jquery
and sqlite.

Your phonegap project will already contain the phonegap.js.

You will need to download and add to your project the jquery.min.js
file

The application will create a database called WebSqlDb with a
table in it called User, which contains three fields  UserId,
FirstName and LastName

When the application is run the firsttime, if the local database does
not exist, the application
will create the database and the table.

The application shows two text boxes which you can use to add values
to the database using the add record button

The application also has a refresh button which will get the data from
the database and show it on the screen

When the application is run on the device the onBodyLoad() function is
called, which sets up the database and table

The Add Record button calls the AddValueToDB() function

The Refresh button calls the ListDBValues() function

There are a few alert statements in this application, which are only
there for debuggin purposes.  They look like this
alert("DEBUGGING: followed by some text");

These are only in the application to indicate where the application is
at when it is processing functions, etc

You will need to comment these out before you deploy/sell your
application

-->


<!-- Change this if you want to allow scaling -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=default-width; user-
scalable=no" />
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

   <title>Embedded Sql Example</title>

<!-- include the next line to use phonegap javascript functions -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></
script>

// have done above with cordova.js also. 

<!-- include the next line to use jquery functions in your application
you must download this and include the directory your html file is in
-->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.min.js"></
script>

// jquery.min.js lives next to index.html

<!-- main scripts used in this example -->
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// global variables
var db;
var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
var maxSize = 65535;

// this is called when an error happens in a transaction
function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
   alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);

}

// this is called when a successful transaction happens
function successCallBack() {
   alert("DEBUGGING: success");
}


function nullHandler(){};

// called when the application loads
function onBodyLoad(){

// This alert is used to make sure the application is loaded correctly
// you can comment this out once you have the application working
alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");

 if (!window.openDatabase) {
   // not all mobile devices support databases  if it does not, the
following alert will display
   // indicating the device will not be albe to run this application
   alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
   return;
 }

// this line tries to open the database base locally on the device
// if it does not exist, it will create it and return a database
object stored in variable db
 db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);

// this line will try to create the table User in the database just
created/openned
 db.transaction(function(tx){

  // you can uncomment this next line if you want the User table to be
empty each time the application runs
  // tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE User',nullHandler,nullHandler);

  // this line actually creates the table User if it does not exist
and sets up the three columns and their types
  // note the UserId column is an auto incrementing column which is
useful if you want to pull back distinct rows
  // easily from the table.
   tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT
NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)',
[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
 },errorHandler,successCallBack);
}


// list the values in the database to the screen using jquery to
update the #lbUsers element
function ListDBValues() {

 if (!window.openDatabase) {
  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
  return;
 }


// this line clears out any content in the #lbUsers element on the
page so that the next few lines will show updated
// content and not just keep repeating lines
 $('#lbUsers').html('');

// this next section will select all the content from the User table
and then go through it row by row
// appending the UserId  FirstName  LastName to the  #lbUsers element
on the page
 db.transaction(function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User;', [],
     function(transaction, result) {
      if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
          var row = result.rows.item(i);
          $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' + row.UserId + '. ' +
row.FirstName+ ' ' + row.LastName);
        }
      }
     },errorHandler);
 },errorHandler,nullHandler);


 return;
}


// this is the function that puts values into the database using the
values from the text boxes on the screen
function AddValueToDB() {

 if (!window.openDatabase) {
   alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
   return;
 }

// this is the section that actually inserts the values into the User
table
 db.transaction(function(transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (?,?)',[$('#txFirstName').val(), $('#txLastName').val()],
     nullHandler,errorHandler);
   });


// this calls the function that will show what is in the User table in
the database
 ListDBValues();

 return false;
}




</script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<h1>WebSQL</h1>
<input id="txFirstName" type="text" placeholder="FirstName">
<input id="txLastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
<input type="button" value="Add record" onClick="AddValueToDB()">
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="ListDBValues()"> <br>
<br>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Currently stored values:</span>
<span id="lbUsers"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

from logcat:

```
E/Web Console(21030): Uncaught ReferenceError: AddValueToDB is not defined:204
E/DataRouter(  154): Opening of the USB File failed fd is -1 & errno is 2
```

The code above is widely cited when searching for cordova/phonegap sql examples. For me it does not work. No error messages are thrown by the app's alerts, and logcat complains that functions defined in the source are unknown. I'm using cordova/phonegap 3.1.0 from the cli. The app runs on a Samsung SGS2/Android 4.1.2.  Why does this demo app not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the body onload="onbodyLoad()". With phonegap, you have to make sure that the device is actually ready using an eventlistener for the deviceready event. Here is the code that I got working. Make sure you have downloaded and included jquery. I'm using version 1.7.2. I also separated the javascript into a separate file so that I could use jslint to debug it. I also changed the doctype to html 5.

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Embedded Sql Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=default-width; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>WebSQL</h1>
    <input id="txFirstName" type="text" placeholder="FirstName">
    <input id="txLastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="button" value="Add record" onClick="AddValueToDB()">
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="ListDBValues()"> <br>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Currently stored values:</span>
    <span id="lbUsers"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js:

```
var app = {
  // Application Constructor
  initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  // Bind Event Listeners
  //
  // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
  // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
  bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },
  // deviceready Event Handler
  //
  // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
  // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    onBodyLoad();
  },
};


// global variables
var db;
var shortName = 'WebSqlDB';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'WebSqlDB';
var maxSize = 65535;

// this is called when an error happens in a transaction
function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
  alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);
}

// this is called when a successful transaction happens
function successCallBack() {
  alert("DEBUGGING: success");
}

function nullHandler() {}

// called when the application loads
function onBodyLoad() {
  // This alert is used to make sure the application is loaded correctly
  // you can comment this out once you have the application working
  alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");

  if (!window.openDatabase) {
    // not all mobile devices support databases  if it does not, the following alert will display
    // indicating the device will not be albe to run this application
    alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
    return;
  }

  // this line tries to open the database base locally on the device
  // if it does not exist, it will create it and return a database object stored in variable db
  db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);

  // this line will try to create the table User in the database just created/openned
  db.transaction(function(tx){

  // you can uncomment this next line if you want the User table to be empty each time the application runs
  // tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE User',nullHandler,nullHandler);

  // this line actually creates the table User if it does not exist and sets up the three columns and their types
  // note the UserId column is an auto incrementing column which is useful if you want to pull back distinct rows
  // easily from the table.
  tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)',
    [], nullHandler, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler, successCallBack);
}


// list the values in the database to the screen using jquery to update the #lbUsers element
function ListDBValues() {
  if (!window.openDatabase) {
    alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
    return;
  }


  // this line clears out any content in the #lbUsers element on the page so that the next few lines will show updated
  // content and not just keep repeating lines
  $('#lbUsers').html('');

  // this next section will select all the content from the User table and then go through it row by row
  // appending the UserId  FirstName  LastName to the  #lbUsers element on the page
  db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User;', [],
    function(transaction, result) {
      if (result !== null && result.rows !== null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
          var row = result.rows.item(i);
          $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' + row.UserId + '. ' + row.FirstName+ ' ' + row.LastName);
        }
      }
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler, nullHandler);
  return;
}

// this is the function that puts values into the database using the values from the text boxes on the screen
function AddValueToDB() {
  if (!window.openDatabase) {
    alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
    return;
  }

  // this is the section that actually inserts the values into the User table
  db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?)',[$('#txFirstName').val(), $('#txLastName').val()],
    nullHandler, errorHandler);
  });

  // this calls the function that will show what is in the User table in the database
  ListDBValues();

  return false;
}
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, still nonfunctional here, although I don't see any obvious errors in the logcat:    http://pastebin.com/24vM2J3T

Comment: Also, none of the debug alerts triggered.

Comment: It works for me and the debug alerts are triggered. Try creating a new phonegap project with this command (phonegap create test com.test), then change www/index.html and www/js/index.js, and add jquery-1.7.2.min.js to www/js. Then run (phonegap run android).

Comment: Also the logcat doesn't help much. What really helps to debug phonegap is javascript logging and debugging: http://www.adamwadeharris.com/setup-remote-debugging-phonegap/

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. There must be something wrong with my installation, I get a form, but no activity (alerts, list) either on my device or on the emulator when I enter data.  Both emulator and phone do respond to entering an alert("hi") into the debug console. This is with your code, the 1.7.2 jquery, etc.

Comment: Works fine, thanks so much. Code error on my part editing your example.